# Mysql get top 3 values from second column, and go to next value of col 1

Tags: mysql

I got one table as below, result of an SQL I've made:

```
COL1  |     COL2
1     |      1
1     |      2
1     |      3
1     |      4
1     |      5
1     |      6
2     |      1
2     |      2
2     |      3
2     |      4
3     |      1
3     |      2
4     |      1
4     |      2
4     |      3
4     |      4
```

So I'd like to get the top 3 values of COL2(even if don't have 3 records, as COL1 - value 3)  taking the result as:

```
COL1  |     COL2
1     |      1
1     |      2
1     |      3
2     |      1
2     |      2
2     |      3
3     |      1
3     |      2
4     |      1
4     |      2
4     |      3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) should work:

```
select * from mytable 
where COL2 between 1 and 3
order by COL1, COL2;
```

Working demo: http://rextester.com/QIIZ51160

**NOTE:** If the top 3 values in each group is not always between 1 and 3, you must use a different approach. This query will give you the top 3 values from the second column for each value in COL1:

```
select COL1, COL2, rank
    from 
        (select COL1, COL2, 
            @rank := IF(@curr = COL1, @rank + 1, 1) AS rank,
            @curr := COL1 
         FROM mytable
         ORDER BY COL1, COL2
        ) ranked
    where rank <= 3;
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/605c7/1/0